# Babel - VueJS | Module build failed: Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In

Tags: vue.js, babeljs

i tried to install preset-env for using environment variables. After that, my VueJS project got an error, i tried `npm r @babel/preset-env`, i tried `npm i --save @babel-core` but nothing changed. Any thoughts?

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", { "modules": false }],
    "stage-3",
  ],
  "plugins": [["transform-runtime", { "polyfill": false, "regenerator": true }]]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with using Babel version from [vue.js webpack template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/develop/template/package.json) repository.

```
npm r babel-core
```

add `"babel-core": "^6.22.1"` to package.json

```
npm i
```